# How do I apply styles to edit-text while typing in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles, spannablestring

There are 2 options available to apply edit-text style on fly. 
One is concat the string with html tags and set text by using Html.fromHtml method. 
Second one is create span objects based on the selected style and set the span into spannable object. 
Now my doubt is "which is better way to apply or change the edit-text style on typing?". 
Can someone explain help me?

Comment: Go for Spannable object

Answer (score 0):

[Spannable](http://Spannable%20%7C%20Android%20Developers) is much more better solution because its faster compared to html process. Also have an easy framework to work with it like [SpannableStringBuilder.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) You can find another libraries to create spannables on the web. Most important thing is in my opinion you can recycle Spannable objects on fly which is memory-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Decided to go with Spannable concept. :-)